# How difficult is the ISTQB Foundation level certification exam?

Tags: certification, istqb

I have to appear for the examination, next week. If anyone has already taken it, please tell about the difficulty of questions that were in the exam.

Were there any out of syllabus questions?

Comment: I found my test fair. It was a mixture of easy and difficult questions. For some questions you can't really learn by hard because they try to find out whether you really understand the topic.  A quick research resulted in a list of [sample questions](http://istqbexamcertification.com/istqb-dumps-download-mock-tests-and-sample-question-papers/) and [sample exams with an online quiz](http://www.testingexcellence.com/istqb-quiz/istqb-sample-exam-questions-testing-fundamentals/). Hope it helps.

Comment: Some questions require learning answer by heart even, or rather especially, when you would answer differently.

Answer (score 3):

The level of difficulty depends on how much you already know before seating for an exam.
Have a go and if you don't pass, don't be upset, review again and try again.

A combination of experience plus revision is a good start.

Review as much as you can and while reviewing, do mockup exams, there are tonnes of it online.

While I was studying I was taking notes and made my own way of studying, applying this now in the advanced level, want to go for the Agile, just as an extra.

I would say, not necessarily in this order, but here it goes:

1. [Review the theory and break it down into the keywords that will fall in the exam, like your own theory shortlist. I've done my own short list tip for each chapter.](http://www.rogeriodasilva.com/istqb-theory-summary/)
2. [For every chapter (based in the ISTQB is 6 chapters) carry out a mockup test, so you can practice for that particular chapter, then repeat until you absorb what each chapter contains. I have done my own mockup tests so I can review it on and on and on. As well as the full mockup exam, pretty much similar with the one in the actual exam. Don't focus on remembering exactly word by word, but in the shape of the questions.](http://www.rogeriodasilva.com/istqb-free-quiz/)
3. Then, to help me visualise it and to help me remember the topics, chapters and the keywords of each part, I have done a mind map.
4. If you are not already working in the industry, a good option to familiarise with the terms and procedures is to try to get a freelance job. This will introduce you to this world and even for the experienced software testers out there, this is a good place to fill in the gap on between contracts.

Hope that helps and good luck with your studying and exam.

Review > practice > repeat > pass!

Answer (score 2):

No, everything will be **IN** syllabus.

1. You can find enough exercises on the internet, please attempt them all before you go.
2. Use your common sense for questions you are unsure of, some questions can be resolved with common sense.
3. Ask for more time if your first language is not English.
4. If you have had experiences in testing career, you will notice all questions are familiar to you.

Answer (score 0):

The exam is very straightforward, if you read the books and materials you should not have a problem - the pass % is also quite low for this exam.

As others have said - attempt all the questions (it is multiple choice) and make sure you understand the core concepts as a minimum and you should be fine.

Good luck